# Spark Dataframe : Is there any option to insert an extra header on a csv

Tags: csv, apache-spark, header, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a CSV file from an API which requires two lines at the top of the CSV file.

The first line would be the name of the program (one column) and the second one a header with a modified name of the columns. I managed to get the second line but I'm not sure I can easily create the first one.

What's the best way to do it?

```
dfb.select("name1","firstname1").write()
       .format("csv")
       .option("header",true)
       .save("file:///home/dse/bin/results.csv");
```

Comment: why the name of the program should be inside file? why not any parameter ?

Comment: you're right, Actually its Program name, Program Version

Comment: so, try passing the **Program name, Program Version** as parameter to spark application and use csv file for data only. Otherwise you can write own **custom input formatter**